# How to report a contact as spam in Whatsapp?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, whatsapp-messenger, motorola-moto-g2, spam

I received a message from a new phone number about some advertising information. When I opened the message I saw "Report Spam" option to report the spam to whatsapp. However once I replied to that message to not to send anymore ads to me, the option for reporting that contact as spam is not visible.

In the menu there is an option to block that contact. However, I feel that blocking a contact is personal choice of an user of whatsapp. And blocking the contact is different from reporting the contact as a spammer right? Or Does the "Block" and "Report Spam" option does the same job?

I haven't added that contact in my phone yet. But I want to report that number as spam to whatsapp. Now that Report Spam option is gone, Is there any method to report a contact as spam even after replying to that contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replying to the contact, the option still gets invisible. But in the menu you can still go and report the contact and block it which reports as spam and blocks it.

- Open contact which you replied and want to mark as spam.
- Open menu, and press "More" and press "Block" option
- There will be three options "Block", "Cancel" and "Report and Block". Press the report and block option to mark the contact as spam and also block it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Don't save the contact and delete the conversation. If the contact messages you again, the option to report as spam and block should technically show up again.

Comment: Okay. But there is no guarantee that the spammer will use the same number to send message again to me. What if I want to block that particular number as spam? Doing that will stop the spammer from sending any messages to anyone in the future.

Comment: @Lucky In that case, your problem solved itself. ;) If it does come from a new number, you already know what to do.

Comment: Ahh! You din't understand my question. Yes we cant report spam for a new number. But what if I replied a known spammer and how do I block that number from sending spams in the future? Got it?

Comment: @Lucky Try deleting the chat. If the option to report doesn't come up... someone else will hopefully report it in future. :P You slipped up on one spammer. Don't slip up on the others. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of two things:

1. Hold your finger on the Spam-chat, and press the crossed-out speaker button at the top. It does not block it, but it mutes it.
2. Go onto the Spam-chat, tap the menu icon (top right), tap more, then tap block.

Then to report it, you can either contact WhatsApp, or just hope for the best. They removed report spam because, ironically, people were spamming it.